# Setting and Verifying TLS min version in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: openssl, ubuntu-22.04

I'm trying to figure out how I can verify that I have enforced a specific TLS version.

I thought that the command:

```
$ openssl cipher -v -s | grep TLSv1
```

would suffice, documentation:
https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/ciphers.html

the -s parameter:

> Only list supported ciphers: those consistent with the security level, and minimum and maximum protocol version.

To enfore TLS>= 1.2 I used two methods.

1. Following the example from Ubuntu man page:
   https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man5/config.5ssl.html

```
$ diff openssl.cnf openssl.cnf_orginal 
1d0
< #
26d24
< 
56d53
< ssl_conf = ssl_configuration
75,81d72
< 
< [ssl_configuration]
< system_default = tls_system_default
< 
< [tls_system_default]
< MinProtocol= TLSv1.2
< MinProtocol = DTLSv1.2
```

reboot machine and issue openssl cipher commnad

```
TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384         TLSv1.3 Kx=any      Au=any   Enc=AESGCM(256)            Mac=AEAD
TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256   TLSv1.3 Kx=any      Au=any   Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD
TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256         TLSv1.3 Kx=any      Au=any   Enc=AESGCM(128)            Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384  TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESGCM(256)            Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384    TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA   Enc=AESGCM(256)            Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384      TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA   Enc=AESGCM(256)            Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305  TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305    TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA   Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305      TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA   Enc=CHACHA20/POLY1305(256) Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256  TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESGCM(128)            Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256    TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA   Enc=AESGCM(128)            Mac=AEAD
DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256      TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA   Enc=AESGCM(128)            Mac=AEAD
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384      TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(256)               Mac=SHA384
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384        TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA   Enc=AES(256)               Mac=SHA384
DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256          TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA   Enc=AES(256)               Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256      TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(128)               Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256        TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA   Enc=AES(128)               Mac=SHA256
DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256          TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA   Enc=AES(128)               Mac=SHA256
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA         TLSv1   Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(256)               Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA           TLSv1   Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA   Enc=AES(256)               Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA         TLSv1   Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(128)               Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA           TLSv1   Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA   Enc=AES(128)               Mac=SHA1
AES256-GCM-SHA384              TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA   Enc=AESGCM(256)            Mac=AEAD
AES128-GCM-SHA256              TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA   Enc=AESGCM(128)            Mac=AEAD
AES256-SHA256                  TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA   Enc=AES(256)               Mac=SHA256
AES128-SHA256                  TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA   Enc=AES(128)               Mac=SHA256
```

Still gives 4 ciphers that can be used by TLSv1

I also tried installing crypto-policies

> https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man8/update-crypto-policies.8.html

and set the level to FUTURE and updating the crypto policies.

But the output is still the same.

OpenSSL on Ubuntu is by default compiled with Security level 2, allowing 112 bits of security

> https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_CTX_set_security_level.html

and since those are all 128 bits I assume that is why they are allowed.

But that means that neither of my settings have any effect.

Is there any other way to verify the local TLS settings for a client machine?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `openssl ciphers` command that you are using cannot be used directly to check the min/max protocol settings that are being enforced. The protocol version that you see against each cipher is the *minimum* protocol version required for that cipher to work. So a cipher that has TLSv1 against it will work in TLSv1, TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2.

The best way to check whether the protocol limits are being enforced is to attempt to connect to a server offering a protocol version that is too old and see if it works. You can do this by using the `openssl s_server` command to create a dummy server.

Create a server.pem file containing a test certificate and private key. You can use the one from OpenSSL [here](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/apps/server.pem).

In the same directory where you created the server.pem file start an instance of s_server:

```
openssl s_server -min_protocol TLSv1.1 -max_protocol TLSv1.1
```

This creates a server that will only talk TLSv1.1.

Now try and connect to it with s_client:

```
openssl s_client
```

This will use the system default settings from the config file. If your settings are correct and >= TLSv1.2 is enforced then the connection will fail with a "alert protocol version" error:

```
$ openssl s_client
CONNECTED(00000003)
4047CB3AC87F0000:error:0A00042E:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert protocol version:../ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1584:SSL alert number 70
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 311 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Comment: Hello Matt, thank you for clearing this up. It seems I had misunderstood the cipher command. This is incredibly useful! (marked as solved)